# Pydub installation problem - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pydub'

Tags: python, audio, pydub

I need an automatic speech transcription tool for my video editing project. I am using python speech recognition library. To split big audio file into small fractions I installed **pydub** and added its functionality in my script. Although I checked and solved the env-path issues of **ffmpeg** it still giving the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "..\VideoEditing\speech_transcript.py", line 4, in <module>
    from pydub import AudioSegment
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pydub'
```

What could be done to solve this issue, any ideas?
Many thanks..

Comment: Just to make sure, have you run `pip install pydub` to install the package?

Comment: I did, even I reboot my pc but no change.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution. Just changed the directory of the downloaded package of **pydub** to:

"C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\site-packages".

Many thanks.